# Move a Sharepoint 2010 List to Sharepoint 2013 without PowerShell or Archive the List

Tags: 2013, 2010, list, move, archive

We are moving from SharePoint 2010 to a SharePoint 2013 environment, which is provided by our mother organization and we have no access to Central Administration or an option to use PowerShell, we only are owners on the new site.

We have a list with workflows and contents on list items on SharePoint 2010 that is 473MB after exporting to .cmp files.

The old server where the list is currently on is going down next year.

This list has contains data which must be kept for 10 years.

What options do we have to move the list to the new environment with the contents?

Alternatively having some kind of archive would be fine, were the relationship/assignment between the list items and attached files is kept.

(Exporting to excel and copying the files from Site Assets doesn't cut it)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

PowerShell is not the only way to get content from a SharePoint. 
Since SP 2010, you can get some datas with REST Request. : https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/ff521587(v%3Doffice.14)

So, you can develop a tool that download your data, put in on SP2013 and use SharePoint Designer to get your workflows.

you can also use third party software like ShareGate which make these moves like a charm.